# Where to start worker threads in electron?

Tags: electron

I want to make a tool similar to [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) in electron. I'm struggling with two design problems.

1. Electron says:

> For long running CPU-heavy tasks, make use of worker threads, consider moving them to the BrowserWindow, or (as a last resort) spawn a dedicated process.

I want to encode many videos in parallel, where do I start additional threads? In the main process, or in a renderer process with web workers?

2. If I have to start threads in the main process, is the correct way to pass information to the main process from a renderer process via Inter-Process Communication? I will be passing information such as a filepath and small strings of encoding settings